# Primefaces Ajax rowEdit is not working

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 5.2. I am trying to edit row in dataTable.

Here is my xhtml:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{manageBean.punchList}" var="att" editable="true" id="detailsDataTable" 
                        >

                <p:columnGroup type="header">
                    <p:row>                         
                        <p:column headerText="In Time"/>                            
                        <p:column headerText="Action"/>
                    </p:row>
                </p:columnGroup>    

                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{manageBean.updateEdited(att)}" />
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"  />           

                <p:column >
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{att.inTime}"/></f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{att.inTime}"/></f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>                                             

                <p:column >
                    <p:rowEditor id="editID">
                        <p:tooltip for="editID" value="Edit" />
                    </p:rowEditor>                 
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

Here is my bean:

```
public void updateEdited(Attend attObj)
    {
        logger.info("***************** updateEdited ***************** ");                   
    }
```

When i click edit and change values and update, method is not getting called.

Any help??

Comment: Please create an [mcve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the rowEdit listener:

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{manageBean.updateEdited}" />
```

And in your ManagedBean, the listener method receives a RowEditEvent:

```
public void updateEdited(RowEditEvent event) {
    Attend myObject = (Attend) event.getObject();
}
```

Comment: I tried my code and it worked. Do you have `<h:form>` tag rounding the datatable? Do you have any error? You can follow the Primefaces showcase [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks buddy..Issue was in my list

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example.

XHTML file:

```
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable value="#{managedBean.myObj}" var="myObj editable="true">

        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{managedBean.onEdit}" update=":messages" />

        <p:column style="width:30%" >
            <h:outputText value="#{myObj.label}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width:50%" >
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output">
                    <h:outputText value="#{myObj.description}" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input">
                    <p:inputText value="#{myObj.description}" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column style="width:20%" >
            <p:rowEditor />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And managedBean:

```
public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) throws ValidatorException {
        MyObj myObj = (MyObj) event.getObject();
        .....
        .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer..Working fine